# Adding Express JS to a Gulp + SASS + Pug Project

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, gulp

I just recently purchased a bootstrap template (https://themes.getbootstrap.com/product/directory-directory-listing-bootstrap-4-theme/) from bootstrapious that is written using Pug, Gulp, and SASS. I should also note that I am relatively new to template engines and Gulp itself.

The past few days I have been working on trying to understand how I can extend the template with Express JS so that I can call routes to call REST functions from my backend Spring Boot Application. However, no luck so far...

What I have tried:

- Creating an Express JS green field project, installing Pug and BrowserSync to compile the .scss files. However, when I call the Pug file from an express route, there's no styles, even though I have imported them. Express JS seems like it's not importing the compiled SASS styles. This seems like the way to go, but I haven't been able to get the styles to be imported correctly so that the page looks like it should which is why I moved onto the second thought process.
- I have also tried to start the express server parallel to when I start the front end using gulp so that I can call the routes from the express server. But this "solution" seems like really bad practice and also hasn't worked...

Is my though process correct that the first option should be the one that I go with? How do you normally include compiled SASS styles into a Pug file? Does anyone have a good example of how to do so? Part of the problem might also be that I can't really wrap my head around how something like this is usually done, since I haven't found a reference implementation that I can base my project on.

So far I haven't found good information on the subject which is why I'm reaching out to the SO Community.

Thanks a bunch beforehand

Comment: Is there a reason you don't serve your bootstrap template themed site as a static resource from your Spring Boot server? I'm trying to understand the competing HTTP server thing.

Comment: Well I could serve the static http files from my Spring Boot server, but I would like to separate front end from back end so I can scale front end and back end separately. If I were to just ignore that for now, there's still the question of how I would add dynamic data from the REST Api to the site itself. Pug would definitely be a help with this since it is meant for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Separation == Great idea. Without seeing the project (which I understand you cannot share) its too difficult to guess about.

Comment: What I could actually share is the gulp file itself (https://gist.github.com/Felix-Seip/45c7a3a6704a6a6cca8cfcdb1d851eaa). If that doesn't help clear things up, do you maybe have a reference implementation of styling pug templates with sass? That would actually be a great start and I could experiment around with that.

Comment: thanks. the default Gulp task (running `gulp` from the command prompt in the project folder) already builds and launches a development server for you. As you edit any of the assets in the project, it recompiles and shows you the output. you have everything you need to develop. Once you're ready to deploy, there are gulp tasks for that too.

Comment: Yea for developing the default JS functions and CSS I'm all set. However, how would I talk to my backend then and await an answer if I have a form for my login for example: `form.form-validate(id="login", action="/", method="POST")`. Usually I use axios with ReactJS to call my REST APIs but I can't call a JS function from the form and wait for a response from my Spring Boot application. At least I haven't found a way to do so

Comment: Write a new javascript file with the appropriate event handlers and AJAX requests. You can use Axios if you prefer or the native fetch() API or XMLHttpRequest object if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the same team that developed the gulp / pug version of the template, also created a reactjs version of it.

Solution was to buy the react version and refund the other one :)